# what happens if you call dll explicit, without declaring in the procedure call its stdcall;

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe7

Testing [this](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm) code:

```
 procedure fii(i:integer);
 var
   Hbar: Thandle;
   Foo: procedure (X: Integer);  //i removed the stdcall here!
 begin
   Hbar := LoadLibrary('BAR.DLL');
   if Hbar >= 32 then { success }
   begin
     Foo := GetProcAddress(HBar, 'FOO');
     ...
     Foo(i); // if we debug trace this to the call of the dll we get not desired value
     ...
     FreeLibrary(HBar);
   end
   else
     MessageDlg('Error: could not find BAR.DLL', mtError, [mbOk], 0)
 end.
```

What will happen if we dropped the `stdcall` in 32 bit or 64 bit ?

The answer is , the value `$18f2dc` passed into `x`. If its a string, it will point to position of `$18f2dc` ,and try to extract the string garbage from there.
This happens because Delphi just pass `Pointer(s)` in the code.
It could changed from run to run and not be `$18f2dc`, but its a 3 byte that are passed. (if you pass int its `$18f2dc` in decimal 1635036).

Does this number has a unique meaning?
Why is `stdcall` needed?

Comment: It's simple: you need to use the same [calling convention](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Procedures_and_Functions) as the DLL. If the DLL exports the function using stdcall you need to declare it as stdcall, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What will happen if we dropped the stdcall in 32 bit?

When no calling convention is specified, then the default of `register` is used. Since this does not match the true calling convention, then garbage will be passed in the parameters.

In this particular case, the function that you call expects the parameters to be passed on the stack. The function will therefore read an integer from the stack. On the other hand, the calling code assumes `register` calling convention and puts the argument in the `EAX` register. Because the calling code did not push the argument onto the stack, the function gets what just happens to be on the stack when the function is called.

To be honest, there's not really much point in trying to reasons about [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)(Application Binary Interface -  the interface between two program modules) mismatches like this. You would really try to reason about what would happen if you declared a different number of arguments on each side of the [interop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability)(Interoperability - property of a product or system, whose interfaces are completely understood, to work with other products or systems) boundary, and that's really little different from using the wrong calling convention. With binary interop you just have to make sure that everything is matching: argument types, return value types, function names, calling convention, the values passed to the function, etc.

> What will happen if we dropped the stdcall in 64 bit?

There is a single calling convention for the Windows x64 platform. The calling convention directives are ignored by the compiler.

Although the 64 bit compiler ignores these directives it is still good practise to include them. That way your code will work when you compile it for 32 bit.

Comment: I compiled the code for 32 bit. and run it on 64 bit while windows do the wow(windows over windows) and the code did not work. i assume it only worked in old Delphi of 16 bit, am i wrong? what is ABI? what is interop?

Comment: What matters is the bitness of the process. Your process is 32 bit and the fact that you run it on a 64 bit machine in the WOW64 emulator doesn't change anything. You still get the 32 bit ABI. ABI and interop are terms that can be found by websearch. Can I let you do that please rather than me doing it and pointing you at the links?